# Cómo permitir que el scroll sea siempre visible en un grid en Smart Devices (Genexus 17)

Tags: android, genexus

Me encuentro con la necesidad de siempre mostrar el scroll vertical de un grid en un SDPanel en Android **(Genexus 17 U6)**. Lo que requerimos es que:

- El scroll sea **vertical** y **siempre visible**.
- El scroll deba aparecer en un grid con un **listado SDT** (&Listado)

Hemos tratado de realizarlo de varias maneras modificando AutoGrow, verificando documentación, etc; pero no hemos tenido éxito.

Actualmente el panel lo tenemos de la siguiente manera:

- Las propiedades del Grid:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Las propiedades de la Tabla "padre" (parent):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional la clase MaterialGridForCombo (clase definida para el grid) se encuentra de la siguiente manera en el Theme:

- Scroll Indicators Visibility = Vertical

Esperamos nos puedan ayudar con este requerimiento =)

Answer (score 0):

Para que el control grid tenga scroll precisas que la propiedad AutoGrow sea "Flase", de esa manera el scroll sera del propio grid una vez la cantidad de elementos que contiene supere el espacio asignado para el mismo.

Si el grid tiene AutoGrow = True, el control crecera de manera de no tener scroll, pero si contiene muchos elementos y supera el tamaño de pantalla, el scroll se te generara en el panel para que puedas navegar todos los elementos.

Dejarlos SIEMPRE visibles no vas a poder, es algo built-in de cada plataforma, y ademas, la propiedad "Scroll Indicators Visibility" solo sirve para iOS en GeneXus. Saludos